# Managing large taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, performance

I've got a vocabulary with 700 terms and [Views term hierarchy weight field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field) enabled (version 7.x-1.6). When adding or movind a term, it starts to recalculate depths for every term, and the "Computing the weight and depth of each term" screen takes more than 3 minutes in a site that is not in production. Vocabulary is not more than 3 levels deep. Drupal version is 7.44.

I disabled the VTHWF module for comparison, and the processing time for adding /moving terms was cut to a tenth, so I thought "great: disable it, move and create, and then re-enable it!"... BUT the missed terms' depths were not recalculated as the module was reenabled.

Any help possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it depends on your local environment. 700 Taxonomy terms are not a lot but calculation might be affected if your local environment is not powerfull enough. To mitigate your performance drawbacks take two steps.

1. Make sure you are using php 7 because it actually has a significant performance increase.
2. Increase your php memory limit to 128MB. Find the memory_limit variable in php.ini file and add 128MB next to it.

Now in the case of your calculation of depth after re-enabling the module issue I guess the correct path to take is the issue queue of the module itself. [Issue Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field)

Comment: Thanks! Really no PHP 7 for us in the near future, poor us... Eventually we discarded VTHWF and used https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge. It turned out to provide us with what we needed, i.e., a way to account for proper order and depth-positioning of any individual term.

Comment: Using PHP7 since last year, but the mentioned vocabulay was torn down to a dozen other vocabularies, so the issue lost its object... Thanks anyway!